# GSON can't render my HTTPServletRequest parameters

Tags: java, ajax, json, httprequest, gson

front end send AJAX calls to backend. I put my parameters in headers.

In backend I use java and GSON to render the data from the HTTPServletRequest

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 WalkIn walkinRequest = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), WalkIn.class);
```

My walkin class looks like this:

```
    static class WalkIn {
       int paymentType;
       int numberOfPassengers;
       int busStopFromId;
       int busStopToId;
    }
```

When I run this on server (apache tomcat) it works. But if I run this local on my computer, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAMED
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getReader(Request.java:802)
```

The parameters are sent, becuase I can reach the data with:

```
req.getParameter("numberOfPassengers")
```

Does anybody have any idea why this GSON/reader  works on the server-side but not local on my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the exception this might not be related to GSON but calling the `getReader` method on the stream.

Found something similar here [link](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/java-lang-IllegalStateException-STREAMED-Consuming-JSON-fails-td3850442.html)

> This exception says "Don't use the reader but use the input stream 
>   because something (maybe header) has been already read from the 
>   stream".

Have you tried it with `getInputStream` instead?